# Mod Rewrite and Arabic characters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, utf-8, arabic

I currently have the following rules in my .htaccess file that work perfectly for the English site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
```

But, on the Arabic website, this throws a "404" error.

Examples that work:

```
http://www.mysitedomain.xyz/work/website/pages/goals-and-objectives
http://www.mysitedomain.xyz/work/website/solutions/banking
```

Examples that DO NOT work:

```
http://www.mysitedomain.xyz/work/website/pages/الاهداف
http://www.mysitedomain.xyz/work/website/solutions/بنوك
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Use `\P{L}` to capture letters; `\P{N}` to capture numbers - http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks but not sure how to implement it. Should I replace the [L] with \P{L} ?

Comment: In your regular expression, you have blocks like `0-9`.... that means __any numeric character__; replace that with `\P{N}` which means __any numeric character__: you also have blocks like `a-zA-Z` which means __any letter in the range A-Z__ (case insensitive); replace that with `\P{L}` which means any Unicode letter.... and read the link I posted, which will help teach about regular expressions

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks Mark. I followed your instructions but all the pages give 404 errors now including English pages. Not sure if I missed anything. Here is the amended .htaccess:

Comment: @MarkBaker RewriteEngine On

Comment: @MarkBaker RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]

Comment: @MarkBaker RewriteRule ^/?([\P{N}\P{L}_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1 [L]

Comment: @MarkBaker RewriteRule ^/?([\P{N}\P{L}_-]+)/([\P{N}\P{L}_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]

Comment: @MarkBaker RewriteRule ^/?([\P{N}\P{L}_-]+)/([\P{N}\P{L}_-]+)/([\P{N}\P{L}_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]

Answer (score 3):

Given your URL layouts, I don't think you really need to be so specific. You probably just want to split on slashes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) this utilize (.*), for any content